# Difference in XPATH results in CRXDE

Tags: java, xpath, aem, crx

I have 2 cq author servers, say A1 and A2.

I executed an XPATH query on A1 and got few results. I created a package using these results and uploaded it to A2.

The content on A2 now looks same as A1, but returns no results when executing the same XPATH query.

Am using `CRXDE -> Tools -> Query` to execute the query

Can someone help me understand why this difference in behavior?

Comment: It's hard to answer on this question without query and content structure (at least). Obviously there is content difference (content which not in the package affects on result). So please, add as more info as you can.

Comment: @Alex it was a CQ bug I think. After it I reinstall CQ and search became work.